# Chrome extension manifest v3: How to get DevTools WS URL from extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I want to get the Browser WS Endpoint of DevTools from my extension. What should I do?

For example, I need this to connect via puppeteer.

Maybe exists API from global chrome object?

Comment: There's no special API for this, so you can use the [standard CDP endpoints](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/#endpoints).

Comment: @wOxxOm, where find port of CDP?

Comment: It's the port you've used in `--remote-debugging-port` parameter as described in the linked article. In other words you can't connect to devtools, you can only connect to this port. On the other hand if you use puppeteer you don't need an additional port anyway because it is already provided by this program.